# java how do u make a loop keep looping with a if else statement

Tags: java, arrays

so i need help. Im using a loop to check an array. However, I need the loop to show the name that was found only after checking all indexes of the array. I have tried many variations of this code. However, I cannot get it to work. It either breaks before checking all the code, loops the JOptionPane box 20 times( which is not what I want) or displays the correct result then the error message. Here is my code:

```
private static String[]name= new String [20];
public static int i=0;
name[i]= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter admin's name into the database:");
String search= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter admin's name to check the database:");
        for (int j=0;j<name.length;j++){
            if (search.equals(name[j])){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name : " +name[j]);
                break;
            else if(!search.equals(name[j])){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name[j]+ "was not found");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Please update the description of the expectation and what problem being faced. It is not clear from the post Also update the question.

Comment: `edit` option should be used to provide more details about your problem/question, not to state that "it is solved", nor to change question into something unrelated to its earlier version. I am not sure what you ware trying to do in your previous edit ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51579557/3)), but that version didn't look as clarification of previous version so I rolled it back to its previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag before the loop and check it after all iterations:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int j=0;j<name.length;j++){
    if (search.equals(name[j])){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name : " +name[j]);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!found) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, search + " was not found");
}
```

This way, the `was not found` message is displayed after all names have been checked, and only if none matched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! however, this would not work, since j is only contained inside the for loop. the if(!found) would not recognise j since it is outside of the for loop.

Comment: @SixZoSeven That's right, edited. It should be `search`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `flag` to mark the search result:

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
        if (search.equals(name[j])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name : " + name[j]);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, +name[j] + "was not found");
    }
```

Comment: A quick typo `boolean found = true;` should be `found = true;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! however, this would not work, since j is only contained inside the for loop. the if(!found) would not recognise j since it is outside of the for loop.